# Use foreach to loop through list (or array) as sequence of pairs

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text, foreach

I'm creating a simple program that reads username and password from Customers.txt file and verifies if it's correct. Customer.txt is formatted to have sequence of the username then password separated by commas (ignore safety concerns for the exercise):

> JohnDoe,1234,JaneDoe,5678,...

Is it possible to create a `foreach` loop to iterate through the `strArray[]` and check pairs {`strArray[0]`, `strArray[1]`} then {`strArray[2]`,`strArray[3]`} and so on to see if user put the right credentials?

```
private void enter_click_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader("Customers.txt");
    string text = reader1.ReadToEnd();
    reader1.Close();

    string[] Strarray = text.Split(',');
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader("Admin.txt");
    string text2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
    reader2.Close();

    string[] AdminArray = text2.Split(',');
    if (username_txt.Text == AdminArray[0] && passwordBox1.Password == AdminArray[1])
    {
        AdminPage admin = new AdminPage();
        admin.Activate();
        admin.Show();
        method.CheckDate();
        return;
    }
    if (username_txt.Text == Strarray[0] && passwordBox1.Password == Strarray[1])
        {
            ATM_Screen atm = new ATM_Screen();
            atm.Activate();
            atm.Show();
            method.CheckDate();
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
var usernames = Strarray.Where((s, i) => { return i % 2 == 0; });
var passwords = Strarray.Where((s, i) => { return i % 2 != 0; });

var userPasswords = usernames.Zip(passwords, (l, r) => new { username = l, password = r });
foreach(var userPassword in userPasswords) {
    if (userPassword.username == "rob" && userPassword.password == "robspassword") {

    }
}
```

Edit based on comment:

You can do this for multiple valid credentials:

```
var allowedCredentials = new List<Tuple<String, String>> { 
    new Tuple<String, String>("Rob", "Robspassword"), 
    new Tuple<String, String> ("SomeoneElse", "SomeoneElsespassword" 
};

var inputCredentials = new List<string> { "Rob","Robspassword","Rob","Notrobspassword" };

var usernames = inputCredentials.Where((s, i) => { return i % 2 == 0; });
var passwords = inputCredentials.Where((s, i) => { return i % 2 != 0; });

var userPasswords = usernames.Zip(passwords, (l, r) => new { username = l, password = r });
foreach(var userPassword in userPasswords) {
    if (allowedCredentials.Any(ac => ac.Item1 == userPassword.username 
           && ac.Item2 == userPassword.password)
    {
        //Valid
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! For the If statement, if in the future I would have 200 usernames and passwords to cycle through,I would have to create 200 If statements for every user?

Comment: @mmoretto Not at all. Check my edit for more details

Answer (score 0):

Using `foreach` is kind of hard to get pairs of elements from sequence:

- you can iterate through sequence normally and remember first element on the odd iterations, perform operation on every even iteration
- you can convert sequence into pairs first using LINQ and indexing or Zip even and odd half.

Collecting pairs approach:

```
 string name;
 bool even = false;
 foreach(var text in items)
 {
     if (even)
     {
         var password = item;
         // check name, password here 
     }
     else
     { 
         name = text;
     }
     even = !even;
  }
```

Zip-based approach

```
  foreach(var pair in items
        .Where((v,id)=>id % 2 == 1) // odd - names
        .Zip(items.Where((v,id)=>id % 2 == 0), // even - passwords
          (name,password)=> new { Name = name, Password = password}))
  {
     // check pair.Name, pair.Password
  }
```

Note: It would be much easier to use regular `for` loop with increment of 2.